# passing min and max variables to another function

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am storing numbers into an array and finding the min and max of the array. the problem is that result isn't reliable. eg. when I store these numbers 15, 20, 5, 30, the expected result should be max:30 and min:5 but instead, the result is max: 5 min: 15.
any help would be appreciated.

```js
var array = [];

function addNum() { 
    var num = document.getElementById("input").value;
    array.push(num);
    document.getElementById("input").value = null;
    document.getElementById("confirmation").innerHTML = "Num " + num + " has been entered.";
  document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = "array: " + array;
}

function clearArray() {
    array.splice(0, array.length); //empties array
}

function findMax(array) {
    var highest = array[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] >= highest) {
            highest = array[i];
        }
    }
    return highest;
}
function findMin(array) {
    var lowest = array[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < lowest) {
            lowest = array[i];
        }
    }
    return lowest;
}
function findMinMax() {
  var max = findMax(array);
  var min = findMin(array);
  console.log("max: " + max);
  console.log("min: " + min);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input id="input" type="text" required="required" />
        <input id="submitbutton" type="button" value="Add" onClick="addNum();" />
        <input id="clearbutton" type="button" value="Clear" onClick="clearArray();" />
        <button onclick="findMinMax()">Find MinMax</button>
        <p id="array"></p>
        <p id="confirmation"></p>
        <div id="display">
            <p id="array"></p>
            <p id="lowest"></p>
            <p id="highest"></p>
        </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You missed declaring the parameter at `function findMinMax() {`. It should be `function findMinMax(array) {`, although I would suggest against using var names that look like type declaration... Edit: same for `addNum()`

Comment: @Ant hi, thanks for answering. unfortunately, your suggestion didn't work. it throws an "array is undefined" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is fine but you where comparing strings not integers ! since youa re getting the value from input , its a string and comparing ascii code of characters going from left to right if one char ascii is greater then the whole string is greater for example `"20" > "1000"` because 2 is greater than 1 in ascii ( 50 > 49 ascii codes )
[check this mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Greater_than)

```
// the array you tried was 
array = ['15', '20', '5', '30']
min : 15 // 1 is the lowest
max : 5 // 5 is the highest
```

all you have to do is **parse the `num` it into an int before adding it to the array** and here the fix :

```js
var array = [];

function addNum() { 
    var num = document.getElementById("input").value;
    array.push(parseInt(num));
    document.getElementById("input").value = null;
    document.getElementById("confirmation").innerHTML = "Num " + num + " has been entered.";
  document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = "array: " + array;
}

function clearArray() {
    array = []; //empties array
    document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = '';
}

function findMax(array) {
    var highest = array[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] >= highest) {
            highest = array[i];
        }
    }
    return highest;
}
function findMin(array) {
    var lowest = array[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < lowest) {
            lowest = array[i];
        }
    }
    return lowest;
}
function findMinMax() {
  var max = findMax(array);
  var min = findMin(array);
  console.log("max: " + max);
  console.log("min: " + min);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input id="input" type="text" required="required" />
        <input id="submitbutton" type="button" value="Add" onClick="addNum();" />
        <input id="clearbutton" type="button" value="Clear" onClick="clearArray();" />
        <button onclick="findMinMax()">Find MinMax</button>
        <p id="array"></p>
        <p id="confirmation"></p>
        <div id="display">
            <p id="array"></p>
            <p id="lowest"></p>
            <p id="highest"></p>
        </div>
  </div>
</body>
```